# Función javascript para alternar el contenido de un div

Tags: javascript

Quiero alternar el contenido de "#booking-table" con "#today" y "#tomorrow". "#today" y "#tomorrow" serán fracciones de código php servidos en la misma página index.php. A su vez "#today" y "#tomorrow" solo deberían mostrarse o el uno o el otro.

Ha quedado resuelta así (no obstante agradecería soluciones más elegantes):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadtoday(){
 $('#booking-table').load('index.php #today');
};

function loadtomorrow(){
 $('#booking-table').load('index.php #tomorrow');
};
function delaytoday(){
 setTimeout("loadtoday()", 60000);
};
setInterval("loadtomorrow()", 120000);
setInterval("delaytoday()", 120000);
</script>
```

```html
<div id="booking-table" class="clear">
<div id="today">
Código php 1.
</div>

<div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
<div id="tomorrow">
Código php 2.
</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo y explicar a que te refieres con alternar?. Si tienes un [mcve] sería mejor

Comment: `#today` y `#tomorrow` son 2 DIVs, pero ¿Es necesario solicitar el PHP cada un minuto, o con cargarlo una vez alcanza? Por otro lado, para ambos, estás cargando la respuesta del mismo `index.php` ¿no deberían cargar contenido diferente?

Comment: Gracias Mariano por tus orientaciones, opté por hide() y show() en lugar de load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código mas que elegante, lo hice para que entiendas mejor el funcionamiento del comando **setInterval**. Como te darás cuenta puedes ingresar código directamente en el setInterval con **function()** cada vez que se ejecute realizara una condición de la bandera cambio y ejecutara una de las funciones que realizaste. Como **setInterval** funciona después de que pasa el tiempo ejecute inicialmente una función (loadtomorrow()) para no tener que esperar todo el tiempo y poder ver un fragmento de la pagina

```
var cambio=true;
loadtomorrow();
setInterval(function(){
  if(cambio){
    loadtoday();
    cambio=false;
  }else{
    loadtomorrow();
    cambio=true;
  }
}, 120000);
```

Comment: De momento no puedo votar tu respuesta. Muchas gracias. Ha sido muy ilustrativo. En un principio yo también ejecutaba una función por defecto para que hubiera contenido, pero no consigo que funcione como quiero, opté por dejar #today, por defecto visible y ocultar por defecto #tomorrow. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las orientaciones. Mi necesidad ha quedado resuelta del siguiente modo:

```js
function showToday(){
  $('#hidden').hide();
  $('#today').show();
}
function showTomorrow(){
  $('#today').hide();
  $('#hidden').show();
}
var flag=false;
setInterval(function(){
  if(flag){
    showToday();
    flag=false;
}else{
  showTomorrow();
  flag=true;
}
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="booking-table">
  <div id="today">
    Código php_1.
  </div>

  <div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
    <div id="tomorrow">
      Código php_2.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```